# Relation between Domain and Range of any function.

Tags: functions, polynomials

If the domain of any function is the set of all real numbers, does it imply that the range also assumes real values only ?

Comment: No. We can have a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\{\text{positive},\text{real},\text{zero}\}$, that sends positive reals to the word “positive”, negative reals to the word “negative”, and zero to the word “zero”. None of the images are real numbers.

Comment: No, there need be no relation whatsoever between the domain and range of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take $f: \mathbb{R} \to \{\triangle, \square \}$, by $f(x) = \triangle$ if $x \ge 0$, and $f(x) = \square$, if $x < 0$. Thus the range doesn't have to be real or complex values...